# Количество букв, которые расположены в строке под тем же номером, что и в алфавите

Tags: python, массивы

Есть массив строк. Требуется в каждом из них посчитать количество букв, которые расположены в строке под тем же номером, что и в алфавите:

```
"IAMDEFANDJKL"
    ↓↓↓   ↓↓↓
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO...

>>> 6
```

Надо что бы было [6, 5, 7], а выводит [7, 3, 7]

```
ewe = ["IAMDEFANDJKL","thedefgh","xyzDEFghijabc"]
def solve(arr):
    a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    b = a.lower()
    count = 0
    arr = " ".join(arr)
    arr = arr.lower()
    arr = arr.split()
    k = 0
    qweq = []
    for i in arr:
        for z in i:
            k = i.find(z)+1
            if k == b.find(z)+1:
                count += 1
        qweq.append(count)
        count = 0
    print(qweq)

solve(ewe)
```

Comment: А как сформулирована задача?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME задача заключается в том чтобы посчитать сколько букв совпадают, а именно их номера

Comment: Заголовок вопроса несколько запутывает

Comment: @илья каробкин Вам дали несколько рабочих ответов. Выберете подходящий и пометьте как решение.

Comment: илья почему вы удалили свой  вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320133

Comment: @S.Nick я задал глупый вопрос, я имею ввиду то что ответом является использование сигналов а я не знаю как с ними работать и мне остается или сформулировать вопрос по другому либо разобраться самому.(простите что потревожил если вы отвечали на него )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно перебирать буквы в слове и сопоставить их к «алфавитной» строке по индексу:

```
x = ["IAMDEFANDJKL","thedefgh","xyzDEFghijabc"]

def solve(arr):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    result = [0] * len(arr)

    for i, word in enumerate(arr):
        for j, letter in enumerate(word):
            if letter.lower() == alphabet[j]: # <--
                result[i] += 1

    return result

print( solve(x) ) # [6, 5, 7]
```

Comment: `list(map(sum, [[1 if alphabet[j].lower() == ewe[i][j].lower() else 0 for j in range(len(ewe[i]))] for i in range(len(ewe))]))` в одну строчку можно )

Comment: `arr.map(word => [...word].filter((letter, i) => letter.toLowerCase() == alphabet[i] ).length)` — JS победил)

Comment: `list(map(sum,map(lambda x: [1 if alphabet[i].lower() == l.lower() else 0 for i,l in enumerate(x)], ewe)))` ну тогда так )) немного короче )

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы не приходилось ничего искать:

```
ewe = ["IAMDEFANDJKL","thedefgh","xyzDEFghijabc"]
for s in ewe:
    ss = s.upper()
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(ss)):
       if ord(ss[i]) - ord('A') == i:
         count += 1
    print(count)
    
6
5
7
```

Answer (score 4):

enumerate собет пары - позиция, значение. Остается посмотреть, сколько пересечений с алфавитом

```
a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
A = set(enumerate(a))

def f(t):
    t = set(enumerate(t.upper()))
    return len(A & t)


ewe = ["IAMDEFANDJKL", "thedefgh", "xyzDEFghijabc"]
print(list(map(f, ewe)))
# [6, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение без индексов. Применим `zip` к строке и алфавиту, отфильтруем по равенству букв, посчитаем длину генератора. У генератора нет длины, сложим единицы по количеству элементов генератора:

```
import string

ewe = ('IAMDEFANDJKL', 'thedefgh', 'xyzDEFghijabc')
print([
    sum(
        1
        for a, b in zip(w.lower(), string.ascii_lowercase)
        if a == b
    ) for w in ewe
])
```

Comment: О, я хотел и с `zip` вариант написать, но не догадался где алфавит по-простому взять )  Можно, кстати, складывать прямо `a == b` и ещё чуть запись сократить

Comment: Про сумму булевых значений знаю. Такой вариант тут уже есть (в вашем ответе). Я его слегка недолюбливаю, поэтому написал по-другому.

Answer (score 0):

Однострочник для разнообразия. По сути тоже самое решение, что у MBo:

```
ewe = ["IAMDEFANDJKL","thedefgh","xyzDEFghijabc"]
print([sum(ord(c) == ord('A') + i for i,c in enumerate(w.upper())) for w in ewe])
```

Вывод:

```
[6, 5, 7]
```