# Как из модуля Dialog считать информацию text_edit в класс Myapp

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Как из модуля `Dialog` считать информацию `text_edit` в класс `Myapp`

**main.py**

```
import sys
import second
import untitled
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Myapp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, second.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.second_wind = Dialog()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.write)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.eating)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.dialog_window)

    def write(self):
        self.label.setText(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText())

    def eating(self):
        if self.radiob.isChecked():
            self.label_2.setText("мальчик")
        elif self.radiob2.isChecked():
            self.label_2.setText("девочка")
        else:
            self.label_2.setText("выбери что-то")

    def dialog_window(self):
        self.second_wind.show()

    def btn_click(self):
        self.label.setText(Dialog.text_edit.toPlainText()) #ОШИБКА 


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, untitled.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_x.clicked.connect(Myapp.btn_click)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    second_app = Myapp()

    second_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**second.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 431, 71))
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 100, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 510, 101, 41))
        self.button2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 160, 451, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.radiob = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radiob.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 300, 82, 17))
        self.radiob.setObjectName("radiob")
        self.radiob2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radiob2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 300, 82, 17))
        self.radiob2.setObjectName("radiob2")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 450, 101, 41))
        self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 340, 311, 91))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "кнопка"))
        self.button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "второе окно"))
        self.radiob.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "мальчик"))
        self.radiob2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "девочка"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "кнопка"))
```

**untitled.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 100, 511, 71))
        self.text_edit.setObjectName("text_edit")
        self.btn_x = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_x.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 210, 75, 23))
        self.btn_x.setObjectName("btn_x")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_x.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], т.е. добавьте все модули чтобы можно было запустить ваше приложение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я отметил для вас строки в которые надо внести изменения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

from second import Ui_MainWindow as Second              # !!!
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow as Untitled          # !!!


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Untitled):                  # !!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
#        self.btn_x.clicked.connect(Myapp.btn_click)             # ---
        

class Myapp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Second):                      # !!! 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.second_wind = Dialog()
        self.second_wind.btn_x.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)    # +++
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.write)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.eating)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.dialog_window)

    def write(self):
        self.label.setText(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText())

    def eating(self):
        if self.radiob.isChecked():
            self.label_2.setText("мальчик")
        elif self.radiob2.isChecked():
            self.label_2.setText("девочка")
        else:
            self.label_2.setText("выбери что-то")

    def dialog_window(self):
        self.second_wind.show()

    def btn_click(self):
#        self.label.setText(Dialog.text_edit.toPlainText())
        self.label.setText(self.second_wind.text_edit.toPlainText()) # +++
        self.second_wind.hide()                                      # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
# ?    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    second_app = Myapp()
    second_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: @ильякаробкин пожалуйста. Мой ответ был полезен для вас?

Comment: Да конечно, все ответы которые я находил раньше писались через сигналы а тут вы просто...., я заметил очень много того что раньше не замечал,спасибо еще раз.